# How do I add jQuery UI icon to a input type text?

Tags: jquery-ui

I want to utilize jQuery ui's icon sheet on one of my input boxes that I'm applying datepicker on. I tried simply putting the classes on the input element itself but it would show the whole row of the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

This is how figured to do it. Since some of the inputs were in a table, I used css and a negative margin-bottom to nullify the extra vertical space caused by the span.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.date').datepicker()
    .each(function(index,element){
        $('<span>').addClass('ui-icon ui-icon-calendar').insertAfter(element).position({
            of: element
            ,my: 'right top'
            ,at: 'right top+2'
        });
    });
});
```